# SQL Query EXCEPT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

If I have a table set up like:

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║  A   ║  B   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ Sam  ║ sec2 ║
║ Sam  ║ sec2 ║
║ Sam  ║ sec2 ║
║ Fred ║ sec1 ║
║ Fred ║ sec2 ║
║ Fred ║ sec1 ║
║ Joe  ║ sec1 ║
║ Joe  ║ sec1 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

I want the result to be

```
╔═════╦══════╗
║  A  ║  B   ║
╠═════╬══════╣
║ Sam ║ sec2 ║
║ Sam ║ sec2 ║
║ Sam ║ sec2 ║
║ Joe ║ sec1 ║
║ Joe ║ sec1 ║
╚═════╩══════╝
```

So basically i want to query the people who are in sec1 OR sec2 but not both and I want to leave duplicates.

My attempt:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM TABLE
WHERE (A = 'SAM' OR A = 'FRED' OR A = 'JOE') AND NOT (B = 'sec1' AND B = 'sec2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, This query is useful if you have other more columns on the table. What the subquery does is it separately gets the `A` which has only unique for `B`. `MAX(B) = MIN(B)` is the same as `COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 1`. The result of the subquery is then joined back on the table itself through column `A`.

```
SELECT  y.*
FROM    tableName y
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  A
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY A
            HAVING  MAX(B) = MIN(B) 
                    AND MAX(B) IN ('sec1', 'sec2')
        ) x ON y.A = x.A
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/491d1/1)

OR

```
SELECT  y.*
FROM    tableName y
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  A
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY A
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 1 
                    AND MAX(B) IN ('sec1', 'sec2')
        ) x ON y.A = x.A
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/491d1/2)

Comment: Hey @JW. can you please explain me the query?

Comment: Im not quite sure with the "x ON y.A = x.A" I dont see where that is derived